# Check the history in Asana

Tags: asana

Just started on Asana and liking it. A couple of queries -

1. Is there a way to check history (log) on Asana Tasks and Projects. Say i want to check if a task has been accidently removed by another person.
2. Can I assign a person just the view rights on a project and not edit rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the activity feed of a task via stories: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/stories

We don't currently have read-only rights.